# How to find the minimum width to display the window title completely

Tags: java, eclipse, dialog, swt

I am maintaining some existing Java code so I am not looking to make major changes to the way it is currently done.  I removed some items from a dialog, (which is fundamentally an org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell) and now the dialog displays much smaller, so small that the title and the menu bar do not display in their entirety.  I can set the minimum width to fix this problem, but since the users may have different screen sizes and resolutions, I would prefer not to attempt a one-size-fits-all width.

I set it to the preferred size, using

```
getShell().computeSize
```

and

```
.setSize
```

and it improved the situation (the menu displays completely), but the dialog title is still being elided.

Is there a way of determining the minimum width of a dialog to display the title completely?

Alternatively, is there a way of getting the title *as it's displayed* (including ellipsis, if any) or of determining if it's being elided?

Comment: Not an answer because this doesn't answer the question. But is there a reason you can't flip the question?  I mean, rather than calculating the minimum dialog width to display a complete dialog title, why don't you just insert enough "whitespace" Layout componentry to occupy enough space in the dialog to account for the size of the previously removed items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IFAIK, there is no way to compute the exact size of a shell so that its title can always be shown unshortened.

While the width of a string can be computed with a *graphics context* like this:

```
GC gc = new GC(shell);
Point titleSize = gc.textExtent("title");
gc.dispose();
int titleWidth = titleSize.x;
```

there is no way to determine a shell's title trim. That is, the space occupied by the close, minimize, and maximize buttons and the system menu (if visible at all).

To get a hint though, it should be possible to use `shell.computeTrim(0, 0, titleSize.x, titleSize.y)`. The returned rectangle's `width` field should give an approximation of the width needed for the shell.